# Get base product image in Magento

Tags: php, image, magento, shopping-cart

I want to get **base** product image in Magento to resize it and display in cart sidebar.

Unfortunatelly this:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(38, 38);
```

prints Magento placeholder image.

Base image is set for this product properly. Small image and thumbnail works great.

No idea what's going on.

**EDIT:**
Solution:
Get full product data this way:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());
```

and then use it as you wish:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(38, 38);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question, but please post it as actual answer rather than inside the question itself. This allows the answer to be voted/accepted and helps us to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear.

Answer (score 21):

I think you are looking for this:

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
        ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() ); //getSmallImage(), getThumbnail()
```

Credit should be given to [BenMarks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/833795/benmarks) who gave this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0).

Comment: `$product->getImage()` returns `null`. With small and thumbnail works. Does it matters its called in **Mage_Checkout_Block_Cart_Sidebar**?

Comment: if you have $item as product in cart try first:

    `$product=Mage::getModel('category/product')->load($item->getId());
    echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
        ->getMediaUrl( $product->getImage() );`

Comment: Jerzy, almost :)

`$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());`

And finally it's working as intended. Dzięki.

Comment: This is good if all you have is the image URL. but as far as I know you can not resize this to any size you want :(

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->keepFrame(false)
->constrainOnly(true)->resize(38,38);
```

Answer (score 3):

**BE AWARE!**

```
$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(38, 38);
```

is **object**, **not url string** it self. Yes, you can use it directly with echo, but shouldn't assign it to var. For example this **wont work**:

```
    $images = array();
    foreach($products as $_product){
        $images[]=$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
        ->resize(38, 38);
    }
```

After foreach, you will have only one last image url saved. Simple way is to get truly string url is:

```
$images = array();
foreach($products as $_product){
    $images_obj = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
    ->resize(38, 38);
    $images[] = (string)$images_obj;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! Helped me out a ton. Instead of adding . '' I converted it to a (string). Not sure if its the best practice.

Comment: I guess more obvious conversion to a string is might be a bit more clear - $images[] = $images_obj.'' >>> $images[] = (string)$images_obj;

Answer (score 2):

The reason this is happening is because the `image` attribute is not loaded in the product listing. Normally you can change this while editing the attribute, but you can't edit those settings for this attribute. I think that's because it is a stock attribute.

TLDR;

```
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET used_in_product_listing = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 106;
```

** Warning, you should not execute this ^^^ query until you are certain your `image` attribute_id for the `catalog_product` entity is 106!

Some answers are suggesting this method:

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getProduct()->getId());

echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(38, 38);
```

You should not do this! This is because you will do a full product load! This is not efficient, and is most likely being done inside of a loop which is even worse! Sorry for screaming!

I usually do not condone direct DB edits, but in this case it was the easiest solution for me:

```
# First make sure we are using all the right IDs, who knows, I have seen some fubar'ed deployments

SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product';
# 10
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'image' AND entity_type_id = 10;
# 106

# Now that we know the exact attribute_id....
UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute SET used_in_product_listing = 1 WHERE attribute_id = 106;
```

Now the `image` attribute data will be automagically loaded on the product listing pages, then you can access it like this:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```

The best part is that you are not loading the entire product in a loop! DO NOT EVER DO THAT EVER

** Also, because I know I am going to get people saying that this is not the Magento way, the alternative would be to create a module that has an SQL setup script that runs the command.

Answer (score 1):

> Small image and thumbnail works great.

Then try small_image instead of image, like this:

```
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(38, 38);
```

Comment: But I want to get base image, not small_image. It matters for me.

Comment: @marco see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src='.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(225, 225).' width=\'225\' height=\'225\'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Magento Product image assigning to Variable**

`$product_image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($productmodel,'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize(width,height).'';`

**Magento Product image assigning to Object**

`$products[] = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($productmodel,'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize(width,height).'';`

It Works for me....

Comment: Appending it to a string is somewhat ambiguous, it would be nicer to typecast it instead. `$product_image = (string) Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($productmodel,'small_image')->keepFrame(true)->resize(width,height);`

Comment: @Ben I have added `.''` at end check my answer now.