# Magento original image resize only shows placeholder image

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to get this piece of code to work in magento 1.7.0...

it only displays the magento placeholder image...

if i change "image" to "small_image" it works fine

everything is set up in the back end the radio buttons are selected for the product images... I have cleared the cache also...

this is happening in the list.phtml file ...

can someone kind enough tell me what i am doing wrong or WHY its not working... i have been searching all over i found one solution after 3 days of searching and it didn't work....

$_item is not defined so a i get a call to a non object error...

here's a link to the answere

[Get base product image in Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11995206/get-base-product-image-in-magento)

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(171, 259);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would try either...

a) Adding `addAttributeToSelect('image')` to the product collection in your List Block (assuming it's local).

...or... (Warning: this is hacky and not best practice)

b) In your list.phtml file, load the full product from the product ID you already have

```
$productId = $_product->getId();
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(171, 259);
```

Comment: Good news! Give it a +1 ;) Did you use (a) or (b)?

Comment: i used the second answer you gave I still don't get why it doesn't load the "image" to resize the first time you kind of have to reload it... any thoughts on it?

Comment: Presumably the $_product you have is part of a collection of products which don't have all of the attributes included. By actually loading the product model, we can access all of its attributes. If you want to add attributes which are selected in the collection, you will need to locate where this collection is being created and add the line described in (a).

Example: $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("image");

This will probably be in a List.php Block class. (However, never edit core files but that is beyond the scope of this thread).

Comment: Thank you... i see what's going on now... I know i shouldn't edit core files and always save it for a last resort, save me from this S**t effort... :)

Comment: NEVER NEVER NEVER load the product in the list.phtml!

Comment: Explanation - sorry to not writing it down with the complainment. Magento uses EAV to save all the attributes in one table (more or less - details...) and if you want to load a product you have to join a few times into this table. To avoid too much joins magento collections only load the attributes you need. You can "easily" change this and add attributes. Using load() in a foreach means: loading 30 products with 1 query and then shoot 1 query per product to the db -> really bad performance.

Comment: Fabian... thank you for correction... can you please explain how to add the attributes without modifying core code... or if there is a trick to it... if you can post it as an answer ... Thank you

Comment: I had the additional problem that I needed to set the store id in one of my shell scripts for this to work. Just in case it might save somebody some time. Mage::app()->setCurrentStore([storeid]);

Answer (score 1):

there is something I didn't find in forums. So I share my solution about the problem, you have to change:
`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` to `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);`

Answer (score 1):

Since this thread comes up in Google first, I put my experience here. The above solution does not work for the view.phtml/media.phtml templates. There the attributes have already been loaded. In my case it didn't work because the memory limit of the server wasn't sufficient for the image resizing process. It did work for the default media template (resize(56)) since it uses default sizes which have already been generated. I added `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M')' to my index.php to fix it.

I didn't think of it right away since my php.ini is already set to 1024M. Magento overrides it in .htaccess (php value memory_limit -1) which somehow does not work for my configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed after I read what @Meyer said. Make sure that that **developer mode** is set to **false** 
this can be done from the root **.htaccess file** by setting this to the end of the file:

`SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE "true"`

and what this will do is set:

`Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);` to `Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(false);` in the index.php file

Answer (score 0):

Check if the collection did load the image attribute:

```
$productId = 1234;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->load($productId);
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'image')->resize(75, 75);
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(75, 75);
echo (string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'thumbnail')->resize(75, 75);
```

if this gives you only some kind of placeholder the collection didn't load the image.

You can either extend your collection like

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image') //or
        ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')  //or
        ->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

or work with the media config instead:

```
$prodImage = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($product->getThumbnail());
```

or use

```
$prodImage = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($productId, 'image', Mage::app()->getStore());
```

**FLAT TABLES**

It might be caused by the flat tables. Check if you have flat tables enabled:

> System > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat
>   Catalog Product

If yes, check if the flat tables contain the image attribute:

```
describe catalog_product_flat_1; // number varies depending on store
```

If the image attribute is not part of the flat tables, just add it to the table by adding following code to app/etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <product>
            <collection>
                <attributes>
                    <image />
               </attributes>
            </collection>
        </product>
    </frontend>
</config>
```