# Magento orriginal image

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

I uploading to store already prepeared images for base_image, small_image and thumbnail

How can I show in product listing page an original image (not from cache) form the gallery, that checked as small_image

```
$_product->getSmallImage();
```

works over catalog/image helper so we getting from it image from cache, but I need to get an Url to my orriginal image, that checked as small_image

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Get original image url Magento (1.6.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0/8288805#8288805)

or

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $_product->getSmallImage(); ?>
```

Comment: And what am I thinking about before that ))) get attribute value and go on. Thanks man, but you forgot to add to path subdirs catalog/product, so final working result is Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $_product->getSmallImage();