# Magento: cropping real images

Tags: magento

When we use:

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')
```

It gives the image cached path. Is there a way to get real image path of the small image because I need to crop the real images using a script.

Comment: Are you trying to get the image url or the server path to that image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the product image url

```
$small_img = $product->getSmallImage();
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($small_img);
```

See [Get original image url Magento (1.6.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0)

To get the product image path (on disk)

```
echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getBaseMediaPath() . $product->getSmallImage();
```

See Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Media_Config
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product/Media/Config.php

Answer (score 0):

May be something this will helpful to you
if you have product object then you can get small_image url like this

```
$url = $_product->getData('small_image');
$actual_url = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$url;
```

This will give you actual path.