# How to get original size image url in magento 2.0

Tags: magento, magento2

I am pretty new in Magento 2.0 and I have been struggling to find out solution. My first question, which I didn't figure out yet, how to reach specific function? Beacuse I noticed that many people use those in Magento 1.+:

```
Mage::helper('cms/page')->
```

or

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')
```

(e.g [Get original image url Magento (1.6.1.0)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8288340/get-original-image-url-magento-1-6-1-0))

but I can't use them in Magento 2.0. If that kind of using is not available in last version anymore, what can I use it as an alternative method to reach functions?

As for another question, I am unable to get original sized image in grid.phtml (catalog listing). Here is how to get images:

```
<?php 
echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->getImageUrl(); 
echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->getWidth(); 
echo $block->getImage($_item, $image)->getHeight();
?>
```

And the result like that:

```
http://192.168.1.4/magento/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/240x300/beff4985b56e3afdbeabfc89641a4582/t/h/thumbnail_1.jpg240300
```

As I mentioned above, I want to get original sized image url instead of small_image. I hope I explained my problems. If anyone has any idea, please let me know it. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the below function to get the Media base url for a particular store:

```
function getMediaBaseUrl() {

$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

$storeManager = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

$currentStore = $storeManager->getStore();
return $currentStore->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
}
```

Using getMediaBaseUrl() function we can find image url in Magento2:

```
echo $block->getMediaBaseUrl() .'catalog/product'. $_product->getImage();
```

Answer (score 3):

1) Quick Solution by directly writing media directory path

```
echo $block->getUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product' . $_product->getImage();
```

2) Getting media directory path using StoreManager class object

```
namespace YourNamespace\YourModule\Block;
class YourModule extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ...        
    )
    {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        ...
    }

    public function getMediaBaseUrl()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager
                    ->getStore()
                    ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
    }
}
```

And then in your module's template (`.phtml`) file, you can write as:

```
echo $block->getMediaBaseUrl() . $_product->getImage();
```